# ImageView changing properties when scrolling ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, scroll

So I developed a simple app for my father to manage his soccer team. The main screen shows a ListView with the player's name, an icon indicating their birthday in the specified month and another icon indicating if the player has paid to use the field that month.

In my code, some ImageViews are intended to change color or Drawable resources according to some actions, like if the player paid their fee that month, the payment ImageView will become green and change to another Drawable resource.

What happens with the ListView is that when there are enough items to make it scroll vertically, some of the ImageViews get their properties changed. Like it's color or it's visibility.

XML:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/llMonth">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvPlayers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btAddPlayer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/add_white"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/lvPlayers"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

JAVA:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    Player player = getItem(position);

    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_player, parent, false);

    Context mContext = convertView.getContext();

    TextView  tvPlayerId   = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPlayerId);
    TextView  tvPlayerName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPlayerName);
    ImageView ivBirthday   = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivPlayerBirthday);
    ImageView ivPayment    = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivPlayerPayment);

    assert player != null;

    tvPlayerId  .setText(player.id);
    tvPlayerName.setText(player.playerName);

    String todayMonthYear = formatDateMonth(new Date());

    if (player.dob.split(" ")[1].equals(todayMonthYear.split(" ")[0])) {
        ivBirthday.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    if (!player.active.equals(getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.active))) {
        tvPlayerName.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getColor(R.color.colorRed));
        tvPlayerName.setTextColor(getContext().getColor(R.color.colorDefaultBG));
        ivPayment.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    } else {
        if (checkPayment(mContext, Integer.parseInt(player.id), todayMonthYear)) {
            ivPayment.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(convertView.getResources(), R.drawable.money,   null));
            ivPayment.setColorFilter  (ResourcesCompat.getColor   (convertView.getResources(), R.color.colorGreen, null));
        }
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

I searched everywhere and couldn't find an answer to this other than switching to RecyclerView.

Comment: what is ur issue with reyclerView?

Comment: @MoustafEL-Saghier I haven't worked with programming for over 3 years now. Got a bit rusty, and I'm still learning how to use recyclerView. I'd have to change around 70% of my code to work with it. Would really like to know what is happening with my listView

Comment: sorry to hear that, if you need an assistant in doing it tell me, please.